# ruby error while pushing puppet code to git

Tags: ruby, git

I have a puppet pre-commit hook setup in git server, while pushing from local I get the following error:

```
remote: /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/path_support.rb:68:in `path=': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/path_support.rb:30:in `initialize'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:357:in `new'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:357:in `paths'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:379:in `path'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:794:in `dirs'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:658:in `each_normal'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:669:in `_all'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:864:in `find'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:864:in `find_inactive_by_path'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:175:in `try_activate'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
remote:         from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
remote:         from <internal:abrt_prelude>:2:in `<compiled>'
```

Comment: What have you done to try and debug the problem further?

Comment: So to debug further, i tried changing the ruby version using rvm(ruby version manager) I tried to install the latest version of ruby (2.2.2) and now my puppet commands are failing.

Answer (score 0):

`pre-commit` hook is normally a [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks), so it should not be installed on the server side, and should not be seen as "`[remote] ...`".

That being said, that same error was seen [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/5YrAUNwd0Ak)

> > The error comes from system ruby.
> >     Have you installed the AIO package?
> >     Maybe it is `facter`.
>
> I just saw that the problem was that by downloading the release of `yum.puppetlabs.com`
>   I used the relational to Red Hat Enterprise.
>   Now downloading the correct release the same error did not happen

As seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557049/6309), this can be also due to conflicting ruby versions.

But in any case, it is nit related to Git directly.